# Playing sound in real-time based on a series of pulses

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I have a black-box that emits signals (say calls a function) at unknown and varying intervals. Each emitted signal marks half a period in a square wave. The goal would be to produce the sound of said square wave.

My original idea was to open a portaudio stream and every time the signal is emitted play a short square wave, then silence. My assumption was that if the signal is emitted 400 times a second then this would result in a 200hz square wave.

Instead on my windows machine I hear a pop then nothing, definitely not what I know a 200hz square wave to be, inside a virtualbox ubuntu installation sometimes I also receive *underrun occured* errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void e(PaError err)
{
    if (err != paNoError)
    {
        Pa_Terminate();
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while using the portaudio stream\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }
}

typedef struct
{
    int play;
} paData;

PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
static PaStream *stream;
static paData data;
static int count;

static int paCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                      unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                      const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                      PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                      void *userData)
{
    paData *data = (paData *)userData;
    float *out = (float *)outputBuffer;
    (void)inputBuffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; i++)
    {
        if (data->play)
        {
            *out++ = 1.0f;
        }
    }
    data->play = 0;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Initializing buzzer\n");

    e(Pa_Initialize());
    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No default output device.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    outputParameters.channelCount = 1;
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(outputParameters.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    e(Pa_OpenStream(&stream, NULL, &outputParameters, 44100, 256, paClipOff, paCallback, &data));
    e(Pa_StartStream(stream));

    struct timespec interval;
    interval.tv_sec = 0;
    interval.tv_nsec = 2500000;

    struct timespec pause;

    pause.tv_sec = 2;
    pause.tv_nsec = 0;

    // emulate the black-box to play a 400hz signal
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        data.play = 1;
        nanosleep(&interval, NULL);
    }
    nanosleep(&pause, NULL);

    e(Pa_StopStream(stream));
    e(Pa_CloseStream(stream));
    Pa_Terminate();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the portaudio library uses the system calls you speak of, but is also cross-platform.

Comment: PortAudio is also just a wrapper for OS specific audio APIs. Windows can be finicky as there are many reasons Jack, WASAPI, WMME, DirectSound, ASIO... can fail. It might be worth verifying which audio driver post audio is trying to use, which you have installed on your system and wether you can run any of the PortAudio examples for each https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio

Comment: I would also confirm you definitely can play a test tone before moving onto triggering something on the audio thread from a message thread